# jQuery and mysql to update data when clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

Is it possible when I click an element that it would update (decrement) my data in a mySQL database?

```
$('#test-leave').click(function() {
    $sql_update = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE test_detail SET test_data - 1 WHERE test_two = '$lorem_ipsum'");
});
```

Comment: It is possible, but not in the manner you're attempting. You need to use AJAX for this. I would also suggest you research the differences between client side (HTML, JS etc) and server side (PHP in this case) code.

Answer (score -1):

You would need a back end function to handle the processed information. It is better to put the query in to the back end. Using something like the above could allow anyone to run queries on your DB. Look at sending a Ajax request to the back end function to trigger the query.

Comment: No one wants to tell someone they are incorrect when they're asking for help.

Answer (score -1):

As Rory said JS is client-side langage and Mysql is server-side so the answer to your question is YES it's possible BUT not as you're trying.

You have to use Ajax as he said to call a script on your server which will do the query. For example, if your application is in PHP :

Jquery :

```
$('#test-leave').click(function(
   var variable = $(this).attr('data-variable'); // Exemple you can get data from the Dom and pass them to your script
   var value    = $(this).attr('data-value');    // Exemple 
  $.get( window.location.origin+"/path/to/your/script", { variable: variable, value : value } );

    })
```

PHP script :

```
$sql_update = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE test_detail SET test_data - 1 WHERE test_two = '$lorem_ipsum'");
```